# formbuilder choose to not show a field in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm building a questionnaire that is  shown in two templates but I need to not show some filed in one of the templates

```
 $builder
            ->add('acceptConsent', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'font-weight-bold'
                ],
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
                'disabled' => $readOnly,
            ])
```

there is any way to set  the form to not render a field?

Comment: Could you add your twig in order to understand better the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "just" not render your `form_row` or `form_widget`

And close your form this way `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}`

So that unrendered fields a not rendered.

Have a look here for more infos:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html